# How to query Standard and Video Post Format with additional condition in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I was able to figure out how to query both the most recent posts that are of Standard and Video post format with the code below:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'posts_per_page'    => 10,
        'tax_query'         => array(
            'relation'    => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video', 'post-format-gallery' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video' ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );
```

This works great with the `OR` condition since I am trying to get both standard and video post format. However, I have to add another taxonomy query but using the `AND` condition. That looks like this:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'posts_per_page'    => 10,
        'tax_query'         => array(
            'relation'    => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video', 'post-format-gallery' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video' ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            // This should be and
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom-regions',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'region-1', 'region-2' ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );
```

As far as I can see, it is not possible to combine (or is it?) the `or` and `and` condition in the tax_query. If it is, is there a way to be able to run this query so I can get both standard or post formats that only fall under certain regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$args = array(
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'tax_query'         => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation'    => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video', 'post-format-gallery' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video' ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom-regions',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'region-1', 'region-2' ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```